# How can I perform a partial match with java.util.regex.*?

Tags: java, regex

I have been using the java.util.regex.* classes for Regular Expression in Java and all good so far. But today I have a different requirement. For example consider the pattern to be "aabb". Now if the input String is aa it will definitely not match, however there is still possibility that if I append bb it becomes aabb and it matches. However if I would have started with cc, no matter what I append it will never match.

I have explored the Pattern and Matcher class but didn't find any way of achieving this.

The input will come from user and system have to wait till pattern matches or it will never match irrespective of any input further.

Any clue?

Thanks.

Comment: What regex have you come up so far?

Comment: So just to get this straight - you're looking to 'continue regexing', so to speak, from the point you left off (without redoing the regex on the entire string), based on additional user input? If so, that's not possible, for reasons I can explain if you confirm this - unless you specify additional constraints.

Comment: Make the `bb` part optional `aa(bb)?`

Comment: Thanks guys for replying. Basically what I want to know is that the String I am trying to match has still possibility of matching with pattern with further input or it will never match at all. The pattern that I have can only have Range [], Sub Range [ - ], * and Digits (/d) and alpha A,B,C,D. Basically any combination of DTMF from dial pad.

Comment: Can you give us an actual example regex you're planning to use? Most answers below require a lot of work if you want to implement them, but perhaps in your actual situation there is a simpler way.

Comment: @amit, so what you want to know is whether or not, at the current state of the input, any additional input could be added such that the regular expression would be satisfied?

Comment: By the way, I'm out for the day starting now, but if you can reply to my comment, when I get back I'll give you an A+ answer ;)

Comment: @incrediman: I wonder what you'll say when you get back to work tomorrow and read Alan Moore's answer :)

Comment: Nice - I didn't realize Java had that functionality; glad I waited :)

Answer (score 42):

You should have looked more closely at the Matcher API; the [`hitEnd()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#hitEnd%28%29) method works exactly as you described:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    String[] ss = { "aabb", "aa", "cc", "aac" };
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("aabb");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("");

    for (String s : ss) {
      m.reset(s);
      if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.printf("%-4s : match%n", s);
      }
      else if (m.hitEnd()) {
        System.out.printf("%-4s : partial match%n", s);
      }
      else {
        System.out.printf("%-4s : no match%n", s);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

output:

```
aabb : match
aa   : partial match
cc   : no match
aac  : no match
```

As far as I know, Java is the only language that exposes this functionality.  There's also the `requireEnd()` method, which tells you if more input could turn a match into a non-match, but I don't think it's relevant in your case.

Both methods were added to support the Scanner class, so it can apply regexes to a stream without requiring the whole stream to be read into memory.

Comment: "As far as I know, Java is the only language that exposes this functionality." -- is this not equivalent to Boost's partial matching? (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/regex/doc/partial_matches.html)

Comment: That is cool. Can you try what `hitEnd()` returns when you match `ABCD` against `A.*BC$`?

Comment: @Tim, I get "partial match", which makes sense, since you can add "BC" to the end and get a match (which I did, and it did).

Comment: @poly: Yes, that does seem to be the same as Java's `hitEnd()`; thanks for the pointer.  I don't see any equivalent for `requireEnd()` though.

Comment: @AlanMoore why doesn't partial matching work for such a pattern: Pattern.compile("(\\w{3})(\\d{7})(\\w{3})")?

Answer (score 25):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(expr);
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
m.find();
```

Comment: Ahhhh I was using m.matches().  Right. Makes sense now.

Comment: What I wanted was to find the method that allows matching part of the *string* to a regex rather than vice versa.  This is the method that will do that

Answer (score 1):

So you want to know not whether a String s matches the regex, but whether there might be a longer String starting with s that would match? Sorry, Regexes can't help you there because you get no access to the internal state of the matcher; you only get the boolean result and any groups you have defined, so you never know *why* a match failed.

If you're willing to hack the JDK libraries, you can extend (or probably fork) `java.util.regex` and give out more information about the matching process. If the match failed because the input was 'used up' the answer would be *true*; if it failed because of character discrimination or other checks it would be *false*. That seems like a lot of work though, because your problem is completely the opposite of what regexes are supposed to do.

Another option: maybe you can simply redefine the task so that you can treat the input as the regexp and match *aabb* against *aa.**? You have to be careful about regex metacharacters, though.

Comment: Re your second paragraph: I'd say "If the match failed because the input was 'used up' *at any time during the match attempt* the answer would be true". After all, the regex engine might have matched until the end once, then backtracked and failed without ever getting back to the end of the string. Like when applying `^A.*BC$` to `ABCD`.

Comment: So it seems that the `hitEnd()` method Alan Moore wrote about does exactly that. Great.

Answer (score 0):

For the example you give you could try to use an anti-pattern to disqualify invalid results. For example "^[^a]" would tell you you're input "c..." can't match your example pattern of "aabb".

Depending on your pattern you may be able to break it up into smaller patterns to check and use multiple matchers and then set their bounds as one match occurs and you move to the next. This approach may work but if you're pattern is complex and can have variable length sub-parts you may end up reimplementing part of the matcher in your own code to adjust the possible bounds of the match to make it more or less greedy. A pseudo-code general idea of this would be:

```
boolean match(String input, Matcher[] subpatterns, int matchStart, int matchEnd){
  matcher = next matcher in list;
  int stop = matchend;
  while(true){
    if matcher.matches input from matchstart -> matchend{
      if match(input, subpatterns, end of current match, end of string){
        return true;
      }else{
        //make this match less greedy
        stop--;
      }
    }else{
      //no match
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

You could then merge this idea with the anti-patterns, and have anti-subpatterns and after each subpattern match you check the next anti-pattern, if it matches you know you have failed, otherwise continue the matching pattern. You would likely want to return something like an enum instead of a boolean (i.e. ALL_MATCHED, PARTIAL_MATCH, ANTI_PATTERN_MATCH, ...)

Again depending on the complexity of your actual pattern that you are trying to match writing the appropriate sub patterns / anti-pattern may be difficult if not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to parse your regex into a sequence of sub-regexes, and then reassemble them in a way that allows you to do partial matches; e.g. "ab*c" has 3 sub-regexes "a", "b*" and "c" which you can then reassemble as "a(b*(c)?)?".

Things get more complicated when the input regex contains alternation and groups, but the same general approach should work.

The problem with this approach is that the resulting regex is more complicated, and could potentially lead to excessive backtracking for complex input regexes.

Answer (score 0):

If you make each character  of the regex optional and relax the multiplicity constraints, you kinda get what you want. Example if you have a matching pattern "aa(abc)+bbbb", you can have a 'possible match' pattern 'a?a?(a?b?c?)*b?b?b?b?'.

This mechanical way of producing possible-match pattern does not cover advanced constructs like forward and backward refs though.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to accomplish this with a state machine (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_machine).  Have your states/transitions represent valid input and one error state.  You can then feed the state machine one character (possibly substring depending on your data) at a time. At any point you can check if your state machine is in the error state.  If it is not in the error state then you know that future input may still match.  If it is in the error state then you know something previously failed and any future input will not make the string valid.