# Determining whether values can potentially match a regular expression, given more input

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

I am currently writing an application in JavaScript where I'm matching input to regular expressions, but I also need to find a way how to match strings to *parts* of the regular expressions.

For example:

```
var invalid = "x",
    potentially = "g",
    valid = "ggg", 
    gReg = /^ggg$/;

gReg.test(invalid); //returns false (correct)
gReg.test(valid);   //returns true (correct)
```

Now I need to find a way to somehow determine that the value of the `potentially` variable doesn't exactly match the `/^ggg$/` expression, BUT with more input, it *potentially* can!

So for example in this case, the `potentially` variable is `g`, but if two more `g`'s are appended to it, it will match the regular expression `/^ggg$/`

But in the case of `invalid`, it can never match the `/^ggg$/` expression, no matter how many characters you append to it.

---

So how can I determine if a string has or doesn't have potential to match a particular regular expression?

Comment: `invalid` and `potentially` have the same length...but the former can never match the expression, whereas the latter can...given more input

Comment: In case of `/^abc$/` what are the potential matches? Is it just `a` and `ab` or does it include `b`, `c`, `bc` or even `ac`? If it is only `a` and `ab`, we can go with `/^a(bc?)?$/`

Comment: The potential matches for `/^abc$/` are `a` and `ab` only

Comment: Could you not just make `potentially` another less strict expression `/^g{1,3}$/` and test that?

Comment: You can get away with `a(bc?)?` for strlen of three. As string grows in length, so would the regex: `/^a(b(cd?)?)?$/` Try writing a regex generator - won't be that hard.

Comment: For a detailed discussion on a near-duplicate question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469231/how-can-i-perform-a-partial-match-with-java-util-regex

Comment: Are there any constraints on your regular expressions?  Are they always going to be simple like `ggg` or can they be arbitrarily complex?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = "abcdefgh";
var len = str.length;
var reg = "";
for(var i = str.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
  //replace '(' with '(?:' to make it non capturing.
  reg = '(' + str[i] + reg + ')?'; 
}
reg = "^" + str[0] + reg + "$";

var regex = new RegExp(reg);
```

Comment: This only works when your regex is a flat string.  If your regex is something like `aaa|bbb`, the results are not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

How about you simply "reverse" your thinking on this, and turn the "potential" into a regex, testing in the other direction, eg

```
var invalid = "x",
    potentially = "g",
    valid = "ggg", 
    validReg = new RegExp("^"+valid+"$"),
    invalidReg = new RegExp(invalid),
    potentialReg = new RegExp(potentially);

//test actual matches
validReg.test(invalid); //returns false (correct)
validReg.test(valid);   //returns true (correct)

//test potential matches
potentialReg.test(valid); //returns true
invalidReg.test(valid);   //returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the test function below isn't going to be exactly what you want ... hopefully it will give you an idea as to how to tackle the problem.

```
function test(reg,string){
   var r = reg.exec(string);
     if(r){
         if(r.pop()){
             return true;
         }
         return "potentially";
     }
     return false;
}

var invalid = "x",
    potentially = "a",
    potentially2 = "ab",
    valid = "abc", 
    gReg = /^a(b(c)?)?$/;

alert(test(gReg,invalid)); //returns false (correct)
alert(test(gReg,potentially));   //returns "potentially" (correct)
alert(test(gReg,potentially2));   //returns "potentially" (correct)
alert(test(gReg,valid));   //returns true (correct)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function have_potential(input, valid) {
    if ( (new RegExp('^' + valid + '$')).test(input) ) return false;
    if ( (new RegExp(input)).test( valid ) ) return true;
    return false;
}

var valid = 'aaa|bbb';

console.log( have_potential('a',valid) )
// true
console.log( have_potential('c',valid) )
// false
console.log( have_potential('aaa',valid) )
// false
```

Edit:
shorten version

```
function have_potential(input, valid) {
    return ( (new RegExp(input)).test( valid ) && !(new RegExp('^' + valid + '$')).test(input) );
}
```

Edit2:
indexOf would be better in first place. function requires flat string inputs and "valid" may contain a list separated by "|"

```
function have_potential(input, valid) {
    return ( valid.indexOf(input) !== -1 && !(new RegExp('^' + valid + '$')).test(input) );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this just works by accident.  

`console.log(have_potential('a|b', valid) // => true`

Comment: if you can ensure your regex only checks flat strings (though that gives up all the power of using a regex in the first place), this solution is great.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general solution. If the regexp is a simple string, like the one in the example (in which case there is no point in using a regexp at all), you can use simple string comparision:

```
var invalid = "x",
potentially = "g",
valid = "ggg";
var gReg = "ggg";

function test(t, s) {
  if (t === s) return true;
  if (t.indexOf(s) === 0) return "potentially";
  return false;
}

test(gReg, invalid);     // false
test(gReg, potentially); // "potentially"
test(gReg, valid);       // true
```

Otherwise you can manually construct another regexp which accepts every prefix of every string gReg accepts. You will have to use ()? a lot.