# Java, getting portion of pattern partially matched by input

Tags: java, regex, matching, partial

As title says, i'd like to get the portion of the **pattern** that is being matched partially by the input; example:

Pattern: aabb
Input string: "aa"

At this point, i'll use hitEnd() method of Matcher class to find out if the pattern is being matched partially, like shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469231/how-can-i-perform-a-partial-match-with-java-util-regex), but i'd also like to find out that specifically "aa" of "aabb" is matched.
Is there any way to do this in java?

Answer (score 0):

This may be dirty, but here We go...

Once you know that some string `hitEnd`, do a second processing:

1. Remove the last character from the string
2. Search with the original regex
3. If It `matches`, then you are over and you have the part of the string
4. If not, go to 1 and repeat the whole process until you match

If test strings can be long, performance may be a problem. So instead of positions from last to first, try searching for blocks.

For example, considering a string of 1,000 chars:

1. Test 1000/2 characters: 1-500. For this example, we consider it matches
2. Test for first 500 chars + 500/2 (1-750 positions). For this example, We consider It does not match. So we know that the position must be placed from 500 to 750
3. Now test 1-625 ((750+500)/2)... If it matches, the positions must exist between 625-750. If it does not match, It must be from 500 to 625
4. ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function in Matcher class. However you could achieve it for example in this way:

```
public String getPartialMatching(String pattern, String input) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    int end = 0;
    while(m.find()){
        end = m.end();
    }
    if (m.hitEnd()) {
        return input.substring(end);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

First, iterate over all matched parts of string and skip them. For example: `input = "aabbaa"` `m.hitEnd()` will return `false` without skipping `aabb`.
Second, validate if the left part of the string partially matches.